# Import "rospkg" could not be resolved

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rospkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using `VSCode` as IDE for my ROS projects. Everything works well, but when I try to import `rospkg`, `VSCode` underlines it with a yellow line and shows warning message: "Import "rospkg" could not be resolved". When I try to run node with this import, `rospkg` works fine, so problem is only with syntax in `VSCode`.

Do you know how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385096/import-%22rospkg%22-could-not-be-resolved/) by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-08-25**:
Hello @Ivan4815162342,

This is a duplicated question of : #q382798, #q256565

I am closing this question. If you think that you couldn't find a solution feel free to re-open this.

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-08-25**:
I have the paths mentioned in the first link, but that doesn't help. The second link is about the `C++` library that is not my case. I should also say that other python imports like `rospy`, `roslaunch`, `rosnode` are not underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @Ivan4815162342,

I think that you have not updated the python interpreter path in VS code.

> When I try to run node with this import, rospkg works fine.

In your terminal, you have to type `which python` then you will get the path of your interpreter.

Now, press Ctrl+Shift+P in VS code and click on Select Interpreter.  Try to set the path that you got from your terminal as a python path. I think it will work and solve your problem.

If you are facing issue or any problem feel free to drop commet.  I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan4815162342](https://answers.ros.org/users/53129/ivan4815162342/) on 2021-08-25**:
This works, thank you!